# How to join to subset of data in another table using criteria

Tags: sql, ssms

I have a table with a number of inflation factors from different studies and want to bring in specific factors as another column in a table with sales data.

I'm getting the following error:
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Here's an example: 
dbo.Inflation

```
ID  Group   Year    Factor  
1   Dog    2010    1.00  
1   Dog    2011    1.01  
1   Dog    2012    1.02  
1   Cat    2010    2.00  
1   Cat    2011    2.10  
1   Cat    2012    2.20  
2   Dog    2010    1.05  
2   Dog    2011    1.04  
2   Dog    2012    1.03  
2   Cat    2010    2.50  
2   Cat    2011    2.40  
2   Cat    2012    2.30
```

dbo.Sales

```
SalesID Year    DogSales    CatSales    TotalSales  
1      2010     50,000      25,000      75,000   
2      2010     10,000      15,000      25,000   
3      2011     75,000      50,000      125,000   
4      2012     12,000      10,000      22,000   
5      2012     40,000      15,000      55,000   
6      2012     40,000      30,000      70,000
```

I want to return Inflation Factors in my Sales table for both Dogs and Cats from the ID that I specify. So if I wanted to use ID 1 Factors for the Dog Factor and ID 2 Factors for the Cat Factor, the results would be as such:

```
SalesID Year    DogSales    CatSales    TotalSales  Dog_     Cat_  
                                                    Factor  Factor  
1      2010     50,000      25,000      75,000      1.00     2.50   
2      2010     10,000      15,000      25,000      1.00     2.50   
3      2011     75,000      50,000      125,000     1.01     2.40   
4      2012     12,000      10,000      22,000      1.02     2.30   
5      2012     40,000      15,000      55,000      1.02     2.30   
6      2012     40,000      30,000      70,000      1.02     2.30
```

I'm trying to use a subquery with an inner join to create this new field, which keeps erroring out.

```
Select distinct
Sales.SalesID
,Sales.Year
,Sales.DogSales
,Sales.CatSales
,Sales.TotalSales
,(SELECT Inflation.Factor from dbo.Inflation INNER JOIN dbo.Sales on Inflation.Year = Sales.Year  where Inflation.ID = 1 and Inflation.Group = 'Dog') as Dog_Factor
,(SELECT Inflation.Factor from dbo.Inflation INNER JOIN dbo.Sales on Inflation.Year = Sales.Year where Inflation.ID = 2 and Inflation.Group = 'Cat') as Cat_Factor

FROM dbo.Sales
```

This gives me the error about returning more than one value, despite only the group of factors I want to join to showing up in the results of the Inflation table when I use those same criteria in a where clause. Also, when I update my subqueries to SELECT TOP 1 instead of just SELECT, the table returns the factors from the correct corresponding Inflation ID and Group but only from Year 2010 for each line, as if it's not recognizing my JOIN criteria, see below:

```
SalesID Year    DogSales    CatSales    TotalSales  Dog_     Cat_  
                                                    Factor  Factor  
1      2010     50,000      25,000      75,000      1.00     2.50   
2      2010     10,000      15,000      25,000      1.00     2.50   
3      2011     75,000      50,000      125,000     1.00     2.50   
4      2012     12,000      10,000      22,000      1.00     2.50   
5      2012     40,000      15,000      55,000      1.00     2.50   
6      2012     40,000      30,000      70,000      1.00     2.50
```

I want to be able to switch between the IDs and Groups as needed but keep the year as my key joining the two tables.

Note I've also tried repeating the join statement joining on the Year after my FROM statement, but I got the same error about too many results. I also tried an outer apply and got the same thing.

Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the inflation table twice, once for dogs and once for cats.

**[DEMO](https://rextester.com/LGCJ72233)**

```
SELECT
    s.*
  , id.factor AS [Dog_Factor]
  , ic.factor AS [Cat_Factor]
FROM dbo.sales s
JOIN dbo.inflation id  -- Dog
  ON id.year = s.year
  AND id.[group] = 'Dog'
  AND id.id = 1
JOIN dbo.inflation ic  -- Cat
  ON ic.year = s.year
  AND ic.[group] = 'Cat'
  AND ic.id = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this :

```
Select 
Sales.SalesID
,Sales.Year
,Sales.DogSales
,Sales.CatSales
,Sales.TotalSales
,MAX(case when Inflation.ID = 1 and Inflation.Group = 'Dog' then Inflation.Factor end) as Dog_Factor
,MAX(case when Inflation.ID = 2 and Inflation.Group = 'Cat'then Inflation.Factor end) as Cat_Factor   
FROM dbo.Sales 
LEFT JOIN dbo.Inflation ON Inflation.Year = Sales.Year
GROUP BY Sales.SalesID
,Sales.Year
,Sales.DogSales
,Sales.CatSales
,Sales.TotalSales
```

Answer (score 0):

When using an inline sub-query, you generally need to correlate it to the outer query, which you do by way of a `WHERE` clause:

```
Select distinct
 s.SalesID
,s.Year
,s.DogSales
,s.CatSales
,s.TotalSales
,(SELECT i.Factor from @Inflation AS i WHERE i.Year = s.Year AND i.ID = 1 and i.[Group] = 'Dog') as Dog_Factor
,(SELECT i.Factor from @Inflation AS i WHERE i.Year = s.Year AND i.ID = 2 and i.[Group] = 'Cat') as Cat_Factor
FROM @Sales AS s
```

Depending on the size of your data set, though, you may get better performance using two `JOIN`s back to `Sales` rather than the correlated sub-queries.

Using two joins to `Sales`:

```
SELECT
  s.SalesID,
  s.Year,
  s.DogSales,
  s.CatSales,
  s.TotalSales,
  d.Factor AS Dog_Factor,
  c.Factor AS Cat_Factor
FROM
  @Sales AS s
  LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      ID,
      [Year],
      Factor
    FROM 
      @Inflation 
    WHERE
      ID = 1
      AND
      [Group] = 'Dog'
  ) AS d
    ON d.Year = s.Year
  LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      ID,
      [Year],
      Factor
    FROM 
      @Inflation 
    WHERE
      ID = 2
      AND
      [Group] = 'Cat'
  ) AS c
    ON c.Year = s.Year
```

Results, either way:

```
+---------+------+----------+----------+------------+------------+------------+
| SalesID | Year | DogSales | CatSales | TotalSales | Dog_Factor | Cat_Factor |
+---------+------+----------+----------+------------+------------+------------+
|       1 | 2010 |   50,000 |   25,000 |     75,000 |       1.00 |       2.50 |
|       2 | 2010 |   10,000 |   15,000 |     25,000 |       1.00 |       2.50 |
|       3 | 2011 |   75,000 |   50,000 |    125,000 |       1.01 |       2.40 |
|       4 | 2012 |   12,000 |   10,000 |     22,000 |       1.02 |       2.30 |
|       5 | 2012 |   40,000 |   15,000 |     55,000 |       1.02 |       2.30 |
|       6 | 2012 |   40,000 |   30,000 |     70,000 |       1.02 |       2.30 |
+---------+------+----------+----------+------------+------------+------------+
```